# Is AWS ECS with Terraform broken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am trying to spin up an ECS cluster with Terraform, but can not make EC2 instances register as container instances in the cluster.

I first tried with the verified module from [Terraform](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/tree/master/examples/complete-ecs), but this seems out dated (ecs-instance-profile has wrong path).

Then I tried with [another module](https://github.com/anrim/terraform-aws-ecs) from *anrim*, but still no container instances. Here is the script I used:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.21.0"

  name               = "ecs-alb-single-svc"
  cidr               = "10.10.10.0/24"
  azs                = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
  private_subnets    = ["10.10.10.0/27", "10.10.10.32/27", "10.10.10.64/27"]
  public_subnets     = ["10.10.10.96/27", "10.10.10.128/27", "10.10.10.160/27"]

  tags = {
    Owner       = "user"
    Environment = "me"
  }
}

module "ecs_cluster" {
  source = "../../modules/cluster"

  name        = "ecs-alb-single-svc"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  vpc_subnets = module.vpc.private_subnets

  tags = {
    Owner       = "user"
    Environment = "me"
  }
}
```

I then created a new ecs cluster (from the aws console) on the same VPC and carefully compared the differences in resources. I managed to find some small differences, fixed them and tried again. But still no container instances!

A fork of the module is available [here](https://github.com/mlundela/terraform-aws-ecs-1).

Comment: It works fine and plenty of people, myself included, use Terraform to create ECS clusters and services. Are you saying you get instances spun up but they aren't joined to an ECS cluster? What do the relevant cloud-init logs have to say?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see instances being created in the autoscaling group? If so, I'd suggest SSHing to one of them (either directly or using a bastion host, eg. see [this module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Guimove/bastion/aws)) and checking [ECS agent logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/logs.html). In my experience those problems are usually related to IAM policies, and that's pretty visible in logs but YMMV.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right ydaetskcoR, but it's likely one of those cases where once you see the logs, you don't need an answer any more :)

Comment: (From Review...Looks like a walk in the ballpark this answer!).

Comment: I added public subnets to the auto scaling group to allow ssh into the container, and that also somehow solved my issue. It was apparently something I overlooked when comparing resources. Do my instances have to be on public network?

Comment: No, but if your instances are in a private subnet, you will need a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to connect to the internet or other AWS services.